# .NET Web Forms getting Page object from HttpContext

Tags: .net, httpcontext

How is it possible to get a reference of Page from HttpContext object.

I have seen type casting like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page
```

The above code gives the Page details. I am unable to understand how this is possible.
Can you please help me understand as in when does HttpContext get the reference to the page. I understand, the HttpContext object is meant to get the details of the current request.
I agree my concepts are a bit shaky. Also I would be grateful if you could suggest some good articles to help me clear this maze :)

Thanks in advance
Nick

Answer (score 1):

Both of them implements IHttpHandler interface.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx

Comment: I'm using signalR, HttpContext.Crrent.Handler is null, is there any other possibility to get the page object?

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: I'm using a custom control in signalR, the problem is my custom controls needs the Page object for registering scripts and serving dynamic resources.

Comment: custom control in signalR ? Confusing. Ask a new question, instead of adding comments to existing question